# Core MVC CheckBox returns false if disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, checkboxlist

How to keep the checkbox defaulted to true and disabled? So that users will not uncheck them but when i add 'disabled' the control return false always to the model object.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input asp-for="HeaderSection" type="checkbox" name="HeaderSection" value="true" class="custom-control-input" disabled id="chkHeader" checked="checked">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkHeader">Header and Static Message</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input asp-for="ImageSection" type="checkbox" name="ImageSection" value="true" class="custom-control-input" disabled id="chkImages" checked="checked">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkImages">Image for each section/ service</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input asp-for="MapSection" type="checkbox" name="MapSection" value="true" class="custom-control-input" id="chkMaps">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkMaps">Google Maps</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled fields are not posted to the server. Your checkbox returns `false` as that is the default boolean value

You can, for example

1. Make it **readonly** instead of disabled
2. Create a hidden input for your disabled checkbox, that will get sent to the server
   `<input hidden name="ImageSection" value="true" />`

If that checkbox is to stay disabled and should always be `true` you could keep it on the frontend, but on the server pass a default value of `true` where it is needed. This way you won't have to worry if someone might tamper with the data sent to the server (you should have validation in place, of course!), but it will add extra work should the business requirement about the checkbox change and its value has to be controlled by the user.